# 'Terminated due to timeout' for large inputs

Tags: c, memory, long-integer

This question is not working for large inputs.

**Problem Statement**

Sherlock is given an array of N integers A0, A1 ... AN-1 by Watson. Now Watson asks Sherlock how many different pairs of indices i and j exist such that i is not equal to j but Ai is equal to Aj.

That is, Sherlock has to count total number of pairs of indices (i, j) where Ai = Aj AND i ≠ j.

**Input Format**
First line contains T, the number of testcases. T test case follows.
Each testcase consists of two lines, first line contains an integer N, size of array.
Next line contains N space separated integers.

**Output Format**
For each testcase, print the required answer in different line.

**Constraints**
1 ≤ T ≤ 10
1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5
1 ≤ A[i] ≤ 10^6

**Sample input**

2

3

1 2 3

3

1 1 2

**Sample output**

0

2

**Explanation**
In the first testcase, no two pair of indices exist which satisfy the given property.
In second testcase as A[0] = A[1](https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/1932/input02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1425807186&Signature=qg8V9o48a%2F%2Fg37tTDdMqXzX8lYE%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) = 1, the pairs of indices (0,1) and (1,0) satisfy the given property.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    long n,*a,i,j,count;
    int opt;
    scanf("%d",&opt);
    while(opt--)
        {
        count=0;
        scanf("%ld",&n);
        a=malloc(sizeof(long)*n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%ld",&a[i]);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                if(a[i]==a[j]&& i!=j)
                    count++;

        printf("%ld\n",count);
    }
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */    
    return 0;
}
```

**Note** : Not working for these inputs

[Input](https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/1932/input02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1425807186&Signature=qg8V9o48a%2F%2Fg37tTDdMqXzX8lYE%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

[Output](https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/1932/output02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1425807189&Signature=Si%2FsUhsCxFu5qOHN3gAR6km%2BQmk%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Comment: 1. Try getting the indentation correct. 2. Use braces. 3. Check the return values from functions e.g. `scanf`. Perhaps use a debugger

Comment: @Gopi Still not working.

Comment: PS: You have a memory leak

Comment: I would try sorting it first. If you know that you're only going to use integers, then I recommend a bucket sort. In the end each same valued number will be grouped together. Then its just a bit of math on the size of groups of same number to figure out how many possible pairs exists (number choose 2).

Comment: Error is - 'Terminated due to timeout'

Comment: @EdHeal Can you point to the memory leak? I was thinking that the error might be because of the large inputs .. as suggested in the answer by R Sahu.

Comment: Error leak because you use malloc but have no corresponding free.

Comment: @Alejandro @EdHeal good thing to point. I forgot `free()` but still it's not doing me any good. Debugger is not able to handle inputs well .Since the input size is very large , I'm not able to point where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an algorithm that uses `O(N^2)` operations.

My suggestion:

1. Sort the numbers first. That will be an `O(N*log(N))` operation.
2. Then, just walk the sorted list. It will be a linear, `O(N)`, operation.

This is how I would change the core algorithm:

```
qsort(a, n, sizeof(long), myCompare);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
   {
      if(a[i]==a[j])
      {
         count++;
      }
      else
      {
         i = j-1;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

And the function used by `qsort`:

```
int myCompare(void* first, void* second)
{
   return (*(long*)first < (*(long*)second));
}
```

Comment: So what you're trying to say is that since my code is taking O(n^2) complexity , that's why it is giving me that error!

Comment: @psychoCoder, that's my hunch.